# Flask app working from curl, not from requests

Tags: python, curl, flask

Below is some code for a rest api I am working on. I obtained this from the tutorial found  [here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask). It is working, and uses the following curl command which will eventually add a tribe.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"data":[ {"group" : "Read a book"}] }' http://localhost:5000/group_es/api/v1.0/group
```

The code for the flask app itself is below.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, make_response, request

app = Flask(__name__)

groups = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'title': u'Buy groceries',
        'description': u'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol', 
        'done': False
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': u'Learn Python',
        'description': u'Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web', 
        'done': False
    }
]

@app.route('/group_es/api/v1.0/group', methods=['GET'])
def get_tribes():
    return jsonify({'group': groups})

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Not found'}), 404)

@app.route('/group_es/api/v1.0/group', methods=['POST'])
def create_group():
    if not request.json or not 'data' in request.json:
        abort(400)
    groups = request.json['data']

    return jsonify({'group': groups}), 20

@app.route('/group_es/api/v1.0/group', methods=['PUT'])
def update_group():
    print 'REQUEST', request.json

    groups = request.json['data']

    return jsonify({'group': groups}), 20
```

Anyway I have attempted to convert the curl command into a python request, using the requests library:

```
import json
from requests import put, post, request

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

In[6]: put('http://localhost:5000/group_es/api/v1.0/group', params={'data': [{'adam':'name'}] }, headers=headers)

Out[6]: <Response [400]>
```

However, it fails, as you can see. I don't know if this is due to the flask library itself, nor due to an incorrect requests command that is not in-sync with curl.

I have also attempted to pass in the headers as a dictionary and dump the data with json

```
resp = put('http://localhost:5000/tribe_es/api/v1.0/tribe', data=json.dumps({'data':'adam'}),headers={'content-type':'application/json'})
```

This causes an error, which I haven't seen before:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('HTTP/1.0 20 UNKNOWN\r\n',))
```

Would be great if anyone could assist as to why `requests` isn't working, yet `curl` works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending JSON here:

```
put('http://localhost:5000/group_es/api/v1.0/group', params={'data': [{'adam':'name'}] }, headers=headers)
```

`params` will encode the data to x-www-url-encoded data. Use the `json` keyword instead; the Content-Type header will be adjusted accordingly so you don't need to set the header manually:

```
put('http://localhost:5000/group_es/api/v1.0/group', json={'data': [{'adam':'name'}] })
```

Your `curl` command line used `POST`, not `PUT`, but your `PUT` handler is also broken. The status actually means your code **worked**, but your `PUT` handler returns status `20`, not `200`:

```
return jsonify({'group': groups}), 20
```

Remove the `, 20`; 200 is the default status code returned. Or use `201` like in the tutorial; meaning *Created* rather than *Ok*:

```
return jsonify({'group': groups}), 201
```

Had you used `post()` instead, you'd have seen your `data=json.dumps()` approach worked correctly. Had you used `-X PUT` with curl you'd probably have seen the same problem with the status code.